# how inverse an cv::Affine3d transformation

Tags: opencv, affinetransform, opencv3.0

I use opencv 3.0.

I use a `cv::Affine3d` declared like this:

> cv::Vec3d om = ...;
>      cv::Vec3d T = ...;
>      cv::Affine3d aff(om, T);

Then I use `aff` to transform X into Y like this:

> cv::Vec3d X;
>   cv::Vec3d Y = aff*X;

Now, I would like do the inverse transformation to transform Y into X?

Comment: where does that affine3d class come from? google only gives Viz module which probably is for visualization instead of computation. if that class provides any getters you can create a mat from it and invert that mat.

Comment: I use opencv 3.0 beta. This class is declared in "opencv2/core/affine.hpp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that

```
cv::Affine3d affInverse = aff.inv(); // Calls inv() on the internal matrix
                                     // and returns a new object from that.

cv::Vec3d xPrime = affInverse * Y;
```

does the trick. See the header you mentioned for more information.

Also, the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions) should provide some more information about the `Matx` stored in `Affine3d`.

Hope that helps!